# Efficient way to create subsequences of list Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures, data-science

So I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    user_id movie_embedding_index
0   6   [998.0, 520.0, 755.0, 684.0, 13.0, 4248.0, 1.0...
1   7   [1216.0, 12.0, 148.0, 1.0, 289.0, 64.0, 110.0,...
2   8   [40.0, 199.0, 42.0, 316.0, 96.0, 34.0, 152.0, ...
3   10  [117.0, 2283.0, 1.0, 25.0, 29.0, 14.0, 11.0, 2...
4   25  [5263.0, 117.0, 5003.0, 5086.0, 34.0, 152.0, 1...
```

Every user_id has a history of movies `[998.0, 520.0, 755.0, 684.0, 13.0, 4248.0]` and I want to create multiple sequences for this user history that encapsulate past history and next movie watched. So for history `[998.0, 520.0, 755.0, 684.0, 13.0, 4248.0]` I would like to create the following sequences:

```
past_history   next_movie
[]             998.0
[998.0]        520.0
[998.0,520.0]  755.0
...
[998.0, 520.0, 755.0, 684.0, 13.0] 4248.0
```

I would like to build this for all users in the dataframe and obtain a final result like:

```
    user_id past_history next_movie
0   6   []             998.0
1   6   [998.0]        520.0
2   6   [998.0,520.0]  755.0
.
.
.
```

I can think of ways of doing this but they are extremely inefficient and don't use pandas methods. Is there any pandas methods that could help to do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this with a simple `explode`, `cumcount` and `slicing` with a lambda. Since we need to apply a method to each row I could only think of a method using apply, maybe someone smarter than me can do better.

```
import pandas as pd 

# if your list is not a true list i.e its a string.
# df['movie_embedding_index'] = df['movie_embedding_index'].map(pd.eval)


s = df.explode('movie_embedding_index')
s = s.assign(seq=s.groupby('user_id').cumcount())

s['movie_embedding_list'] = s['user_id'].map(df.set_index('user_id')['movie_embedding_index'])
s['movie_embedding_list'] =  s.apply(lambda x : x['movie_embedding_list'][:x['seq']],1)
```

---

```
print(s.drop('seq',1)

   user_id movie_embedding_index                          movie_embedding_list
0        6                   998                                            []
0        6                   520                                       [998.0]
0        6                   755                                [998.0, 520.0]
0        6                   684                         [998.0, 520.0, 755.0]
0        6                    13                  [998.0, 520.0, 755.0, 684.0]
0        6                  4248            [998.0, 520.0, 755.0, 684.0, 13.0]
0        6                     1    [998.0, 520.0, 755.0, 684.0, 13.0, 4248.0]
1        7                  1216                                            []
1        7                    12                                      [1216.0]
1        7                   148                                [1216.0, 12.0]
1        7                     1                         [1216.0, 12.0, 148.0]
1        7                   289                    [1216.0, 12.0, 148.0, 1.0]
1        7                    64             [1216.0, 12.0, 148.0, 1.0, 289.0]
1        7                   110       [1216.0, 12.0, 148.0, 1.0, 289.0, 64.0]
2        8                    40                                            []
2        8                   199                                        [40.0]
2        8                    42                                 [40.0, 199.0]
2        8                   316                           [40.0, 199.0, 42.0]
2        8                    96                    [40.0, 199.0, 42.0, 316.0]
2        8                    34              [40.0, 199.0, 42.0, 316.0, 96.0]
2        8                   152        [40.0, 199.0, 42.0, 316.0, 96.0, 34.0]
3       10                   117                                            []
3       10                  2283                                       [117.0]
3       10                     1                               [117.0, 2283.0]
3       10                    25                          [117.0, 2283.0, 1.0]
3       10                    29                    [117.0, 2283.0, 1.0, 25.0]
3       10                    14              [117.0, 2283.0, 1.0, 25.0, 29.0]
3       10                    11        [117.0, 2283.0, 1.0, 25.0, 29.0, 14.0]
3       10                     2  [117.0, 2283.0, 1.0, 25.0, 29.0, 14.0, 11.0]
4       25                  5263                                            []
4       25                   117                                      [5263.0]
4       25                  5003                               [5263.0, 117.0]
4       25                  5086                       [5263.0, 117.0, 5003.0]
4       25                    34               [5263.0, 117.0, 5003.0, 5086.0]
4       25                   152         [5263.0, 117.0, 5003.0, 5086.0, 34.0]
4       25                     1  [5263.0, 117.0, 5003.0, 5086.0, 34.0, 152.0]
```

Comment: Hi Manakin. Just a quick note - there is no need to add "IIUC" to each of your answers. If you are not sure whether you understand a post, it is better to clarify in the comments first, which will pave the way to answering confidently and without caveats. My experience is that ESL folks struggle with acronyms of this kind anyway.

Comment: @halfer, it's a bad habit I've picked up, thanks for the - heads up.

Answer (score 2):

A solution could be to first call `apply` with the calculation you want.

```
import pandas as pd

# Generate an example dataframe
d = {'user_id': [1, 2, 3], 'movie_embedding_index': [[998.0, 520.0, 755.0, 684.0, 13.0, 4248.0], [98.0, 20.0, 55.0, 84.0], [132.0, 5432.0, 97-0, 675.0]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# Calculate lists of past movies and current movie
df['calculation'] = df.movie_embedding_index.apply(lambda x: [(x[:index], elem) for index, elem in enumerate(x, start=0)])
```

then apply `explode` on this calculation column

```
df = df.explode('calculation')
```

and finally retrieve those values as new columns

```
df['past_history'] = df['calculation'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
df['next_movie'] = df['calculation'].apply(lambda x: x[1])
```

**Final Result**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- sample data has eclipses (...) continuation chars.  a bit of massaging to make it valid lists
- within `lambda` function list comprehension to build `dict` of **watched** and **next**
- `explode()` list in step above into rows
- `apply(pd.Series)` to expand `dict` into columns
- `join()` back to original data frame

```
import json

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""    user_id  movie_embedding_index
0   6   [998.0, 520.0, 755.0, 684.0, 13.0, 4248.0, 1.0...
1   7   [1216.0, 12.0, 148.0, 1.0, 289.0, 64.0, 110.0,...
2   8   [40.0, 199.0, 42.0, 316.0, 96.0, 34.0, 152.0, ...
3   10  [117.0, 2283.0, 1.0, 25.0, 29.0, 14.0, 11.0, 2...
4   25  [5263.0, 117.0, 5003.0, 5086.0, 34.0, 152.0, 1..."""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")
df.movie_embedding_index = (df.movie_embedding_index.str.strip(". ,")+"]").apply(lambda s: json.loads(s))

df = df.join(df.movie_embedding_index.apply(lambda l: [{"watched":l[0:i],"next":m} 
                                                  for i,m in enumerate(l)]).explode().apply(pd.Series))
```

|  | user_id | movie_embedding_index | watched | next |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 6 | [998.0, 520.0, 755.0, 684.0, 13.0, 4248.0, 1.0] | [] | 998 |
| 0 | 6 | [998.0, 520.0, 755.0, 684.0, 13.0, 4248.0, 1.0] | [998.0] | 520 |
| 0 | 6 | [998.0, 520.0, 755.0, 684.0, 13.0, 4248.0, 1.0] | [998.0, 520.0] | 755 |
| 0 | 6 | [998.0, 520.0, 755.0, 684.0, 13.0, 4248.0, 1.0] | [998.0, 520.0, 755.0] | 684 |
| 0 | 6 | [998.0, 520.0, 755.0, 684.0, 13.0, 4248.0, 1.0] | [998.0, 520.0, 755.0, 684.0] | 13 |
| 0 | 6 | [998.0, 520.0, 755.0, 684.0, 13.0, 4248.0, 1.0] | [998.0, 520.0, 755.0, 684.0, 13.0] | 4248 |
| 0 | 6 | [998.0, 520.0, 755.0, 684.0, 13.0, 4248.0, 1.0] | [998.0, 520.0, 755.0, 684.0, 13.0, 4248.0] | 1 |
| 1 | 7 | [1216.0, 12.0, 148.0, 1.0, 289.0, 64.0, 110.0] | [] | 1216 |
| 1 | 7 | [1216.0, 12.0, 148.0, 1.0, 289.0, 64.0, 110.0] | [1216.0] | 12 |
| 1 | 7 | [1216.0, 12.0, 148.0, 1.0, 289.0, 64.0, 110.0] | [1216.0, 12.0] | 148 |
| 1 | 7 | [1216.0, 12.0, 148.0, 1.0, 289.0, 64.0, 110.0] | [1216.0, 12.0, 148.0] | 1 |
| 1 | 7 | [1216.0, 12.0, 148.0, 1.0, 289.0, 64.0, 110.0] | [1216.0, 12.0, 148.0, 1.0] | 289 |
| 1 | 7 | [1216.0, 12.0, 148.0, 1.0, 289.0, 64.0, 110.0] | [1216.0, 12.0, 148.0, 1.0, 289.0] | 64 |
| 1 | 7 | [1216.0, 12.0, 148.0, 1.0, 289.0, 64.0, 110.0] | [1216.0, 12.0, 148.0, 1.0, 289.0, 64.0] | 110 |
| 2 | 8 | [40.0, 199.0, 42.0, 316.0, 96.0, 34.0, 152.0] | [] | 40 |
| 2 | 8 | [40.0, 199.0, 42.0, 316.0, 96.0, 34.0, 152.0] | [40.0] | 199 |
| 2 | 8 | [40.0, 199.0, 42.0, 316.0, 96.0, 34.0, 152.0] | [40.0, 199.0] | 42 |
| 2 | 8 | [40.0, 199.0, 42.0, 316.0, 96.0, 34.0, 152.0] | [40.0, 199.0, 42.0] | 316 |
| 2 | 8 | [40.0, 199.0, 42.0, 316.0, 96.0, 34.0, 152.0] | [40.0, 199.0, 42.0, 316.0] | 96 |
| 2 | 8 | [40.0, 199.0, 42.0, 316.0, 96.0, 34.0, 152.0] | [40.0, 199.0, 42.0, 316.0, 96.0] | 34 |
| 2 | 8 | [40.0, 199.0, 42.0, 316.0, 96.0, 34.0, 152.0] | [40.0, 199.0, 42.0, 316.0, 96.0, 34.0] | 152 |
| 3 | 10 | [117.0, 2283.0, 1.0, 25.0, 29.0, 14.0, 11.0, 2] | [] | 117 |
| 3 | 10 | [117.0, 2283.0, 1.0, 25.0, 29.0, 14.0, 11.0, 2] | [117.0] | 2283 |
| 3 | 10 | [117.0, 2283.0, 1.0, 25.0, 29.0, 14.0, 11.0, 2] | [117.0, 2283.0] | 1 |
| 3 | 10 | [117.0, 2283.0, 1.0, 25.0, 29.0, 14.0, 11.0, 2] | [117.0, 2283.0, 1.0] | 25 |
| 3 | 10 | [117.0, 2283.0, 1.0, 25.0, 29.0, 14.0, 11.0, 2] | [117.0, 2283.0, 1.0, 25.0] | 29 |
| 3 | 10 | [117.0, 2283.0, 1.0, 25.0, 29.0, 14.0, 11.0, 2] | [117.0, 2283.0, 1.0, 25.0, 29.0] | 14 |
| 3 | 10 | [117.0, 2283.0, 1.0, 25.0, 29.0, 14.0, 11.0, 2] | [117.0, 2283.0, 1.0, 25.0, 29.0, 14.0] | 11 |
| 3 | 10 | [117.0, 2283.0, 1.0, 25.0, 29.0, 14.0, 11.0, 2] | [117.0, 2283.0, 1.0, 25.0, 29.0, 14.0, 11.0] | 2 |
| 4 | 25 | [5263.0, 117.0, 5003.0, 5086.0, 34.0, 152.0, 1] | [] | 5263 |
| 4 | 25 | [5263.0, 117.0, 5003.0, 5086.0, 34.0, 152.0, 1] | [5263.0] | 117 |
| 4 | 25 | [5263.0, 117.0, 5003.0, 5086.0, 34.0, 152.0, 1] | [5263.0, 117.0] | 5003 |
| 4 | 25 | [5263.0, 117.0, 5003.0, 5086.0, 34.0, 152.0, 1] | [5263.0, 117.0, 5003.0] | 5086 |
| 4 | 25 | [5263.0, 117.0, 5003.0, 5086.0, 34.0, 152.0, 1] | [5263.0, 117.0, 5003.0, 5086.0] | 34 |
| 4 | 25 | [5263.0, 117.0, 5003.0, 5086.0, 34.0, 152.0, 1] | [5263.0, 117.0, 5003.0, 5086.0, 34.0] | 152 |
| 4 | 25 | [5263.0, 117.0, 5003.0, 5086.0, 34.0, 152.0, 1] | [5263.0, 117.0, 5003.0, 5086.0, 34.0, 152.0] | 1 |